# CSS - Wavy border

Tags: html, css

I need to create a wavy border for a div and I am trying to do that with pure CSS, no images.

I know there is this answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/create-wavy-border-with-css), but what I want to create is an infinite sine wave as border.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 to counter act the loser who marks you down without comment.

Comment: One more possibility to do this: http://neisbut.github.io/textAnnotator/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no use hacking CSS to do things like this when other tools offer it much easier and less tricky way. You could for example use some SVG vector graphics to do something like this.

Comment: SVG Vector Graphics? Is that some kind of recursive backronym like PHP Hypertext Preprocessor?

Answer (score -1):

I finnally got it. You just have to use multiple radial gradients, using elipses and changing each background position to fit into the wave. Then, you just need to repeat it :)

See [this link](http://wing.inf.br/DiaDoPublicitario/) to get the effect

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @Guilhermevrs Please add some code to your answer :)