# Css Shape Creation Curved Wave

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: How this Css shapes are created]

[This is what i have got so far](http://jsfiddle.net/hQ74b/1/) 
[After after checking out tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/DYYWU/1/)

- I want know how curved effect is generated on divs the only question that i found near to what i was looking for was [At here at stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/create-wavy-border-with-css)  but that too dint help
  [image]
- How folded edge effect is created on as in the above picture

### Css

```
#MenuShape{
   height:50px;
   background-color:orange; 
   width:200px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    left:100px;

}
#MenuShape:after{
        content:"";
   position: absolute;
    width: 0;
   height: 0;
   left:200px;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;

}
#MenuShape:before{
        content:"";
   position: absolute;
    width: 0;
   height: -50;
   left:-100px;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;

}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="MenuShape"  >
    sachin

</div>
```

https://css-tricks.com/ this the site on inspecting it i found its span wrapped 
anchor tag along with svg tag

```
  <a href="/" class="home">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 25" class="shape-tab">
      <use xlink:href="#shape-tab"></use>
    </svg>

  <span>Blog</span></a>
```

[Click here to see the unexpected behaviour it  works fine in codepen](http://jsfiddle.net/vwZWr)

Comment: Stuff like that is generally done with an image.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/ this the site on inspecting it

Comment: Well, you can clearly see that the site uses an `<svg>` element... which is basically a (vector) image.

Comment: Okay i dint know about that

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/

Comment: Actually, if you want those specific tabs, their creation is detailed in [this more recent tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/).  They use inline SVG icons.

Comment: BUt can you explain why is this happening http://jsfiddle.net/vwZWr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [final demo](https://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-folded-corner-effect/demo/) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109035740/http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-folded-corner-effect/demo/)) on the folded corners:

and the following code is how you can create them:

```css
.note {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: #97C02F;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.note:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff #fff #658E15 #658E15;
  background: #658E15;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Firefox 3.0 damage limitation */
  display: block;
  width: 0;
}

.note.rounded {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}

.note.rounded:before {
  border-width: 8px;
  border-color: #fff #fff transparent transparent;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="note"></div>
```

To create a curved wave effect you can use this code:

```css
#wave {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #e0efe3;
}

#wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 340px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  right: -5px;
  top: 40px;
}

#wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #e0efe3;
  left: 0;
  top: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wave"></div>
```

To achieve the curve you’ll need to inverse where it starts. Follow the same demo, just reverse your values.

See a [live demonstration](https://www.cssmatic.com/border-radius) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513023657/https://www.cssmatic.com/border-radius)) of how border radius can create the shapes and effects you want and adjust each corner to see it in action.

Comment: To change exactly where you want the curve to take effect on your shape youll want to play with your values. Specifically the border-radius values ... Tweak them to get the curve where you want it (left right bottom top etc), and how dramatic of a curve you want.

Comment: How would one use this method for the wave as a full-width, responsive background? It seems like the changing inner-width would cause havoc with the ovals being created in the :before and :after.

Comment: Unfortunately because of static values this wouldnt be possible. The only way to achieve that would be to use media queries and change your wave for different resolutions.