# Create a Shape ONLY with CSS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, css-shapes

I need to create this custom shape with **only** CSS3.

[image: divider of sections]

Need to be with CSS, not svg.
I was trying to use the snippets of this link: [Wave (or shape?) with border on CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777470/wave-or-shape-with-border-on-css3/27780572#27780572) but i don't know how to manipulate shapes properly.

Also can be only the center shape! I'm testing with this pen: https://codepen.io/Blumenkranz/pen/vYEeLjr

```
@mixin push--auto {
    margin: { 
        left: auto;
        right: auto;
    }
}
@mixin pseudo($display: block, $pos: absolute, $content: "") {
  content: $content;
  display: $display;
  position: $pos;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: $blue-dark;
  position:relative;
   &::after, &::before {
    @include pseudo;
    @include  push--auto;
    bottom: -46px; 
    left: 35%;
    width: 250px; 
    height: 150px;
    background: $blue-dark;
   border-radius: 100%;

}
}
```

Comment: To draw that you will need to draw elliptical curves—something that CSS struggle with. Why can’t you use a base64 encoded SVG background image?

Comment: Because this is a challenge for a job... i can't use images, only css to draw everything

Comment: +1 for a tough question.  It's bugging me that I can't get there, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034962/css-shape-creation-curved-wave) and [the JSFiddle linked in it](http://jsfiddle.net/DYYWU/1/) might point you in the right direction.  There are also some answers that are somewhat close to what you're looking for..

Comment: @mtr.web i kinda need to make inverse border radius... this one is simple... and i need to fill the shape inside, not outside... I'm still trying here.

Comment: You could try three ovals 1. white (left) 2. blue (center) 3. white (right) https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/ and work on overlapping them to create the effect. Not perfect, but might work.

Comment: Tell them if they don't want the job done the right way they are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Sounds promising @NathanielFlick. I'll try it, and post the result. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to make this using only css, as svg would be much simpler, but here you go. I made an approximation of your shape, which you can easily adjust, using a similar technique to the one you linked.

[image: 1]

Here is the code. I'm using display flex on the body and margin auto on the container to position it in the center of the page for display purposes.

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 height: 100vh;
}
.container {
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
}
.shape {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #157995;
 transform: rotate(45deg) skew(-10deg,-10deg);
 clip-path: polygon(68% 100%, 100% 68%, 100% 100%);
 border-radius: 15%;
}
.bar {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 width: 80%;
 height: 12px;
 background-color: #157995;
}
.container::before, .container::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 0px;
}
.container::before {
 left: 12.4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 50%;
 transform: skew(55deg);
}
.container::after {
 right: 12.4px;
 border-top-left-radius: 50%;
 transform: skew(-55deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="shape"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This definitely fits. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the party here, but this was my effort using:

- a transparent container (with a visible top border)
- two background-coloured pseudo-elements inside the transparent container
- a slim horizontal rectangle; and
- a circle

**Working Example:**

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 123, 149);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 123, 149);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: calc(50% - 64px);
  width: 128px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 123, 149);
}

.line::before,
.line::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
z-index: 24;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.line::before {
left: calc(50% - 110px);
}

.line::after {
right: calc(50% - 110px);
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloring something `#fff` just to coverup shape is not the way to go.

Comment: Conceded, the approach above won't work if the background is anything but a uniformly coloured field.

Comment: Not only that, Say the *tougue shape* is a fixed element, some page content and text that is scrolled underneath will be affected (covered) by the white shape as well.

Comment: Absolutely. I'd be tempted to say that's pretty much the same background issue.

Comment: Well, yes, just another similar case. But thanks for sharing and don't feel discouraged by my comments.

Comment: Strange no-one mentioned a simple SVG shape... ;)

Comment: Not at all, I appreciated your feedback. I started working on a solution several days ago when I saw the question after thinking it might be possible with 3 elements and 2 pseudo-elements. Then I got distracted and lost the tab. This afternoon I am tidying up tabs and came across it (I thought it was long closed). I couldn't bring myself to close the tab without finishing the solution - and I would be the first to agree that it's really not my best work.

Comment: (* Because the question stipulates the solution must be a CSS solution).

Comment: I can say SVG is tightly coupled with HTML (the first best thing), and doing it with SVG one would have better browser coverage than using the accepted `clip-path polygon` - [clip CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) - [SVG CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg)

Comment: Actually not too late at all. 
I can practice with your solution, making some changes to fit in what i needed. i'm learning too :)