# How to draw a curve by using div?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I need to draw two curves, using CSS.
I have tried to assemble some `div`s, using CSS `border-radius` to draw the curved panel. But the result is bad. Any better arithmetic?

[image]

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: could you just create that as an image instead?

Comment: You can have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777470/wave-or-shape-with-border-on-css3/27780572#27780572) but **please don't use CSS** for this. Double curves are many times easier done with SVG.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I had mentioned in comments earlier, **please do not use CSS** for achieving complex curves and shapes. While it is still possible to use CSS to achieve them (using `transform` + pseudo-elements like shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777470/wave-or-shape-with-border-on-css3/27780572#27780572) or using `box-shadows` in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986125/double-curved-shape/28988476#28988476)),  the process is very complex and you can't get much control over the shape, its curvature etc also. SVG on the other hand is designed for such graphics and it can also be scaled without any issues.

Below is a sample snippet on how to create the shape using a couple of [cubic bezier curve (`c`) commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d). The cubic bezier curve command takes 3 sets of parameters in total where the first two sets represent the coordinates of the control points for the initial and end points of the curve and the last set represents the coordinates of the actual end point of the curve.

You can control the curvature by modifying the control points.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.items {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  transform: translateX(100%) translateY(-50%);
}
path {
  stroke: #AAA;
  fill: #DDD;
}
line {
  stroke: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
  </div>
  <div class="shape">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 50 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
      <path d='M0,0 
               c10,15 40,15 48,35 
               v30 
               c-8,20 -38,20 -48,35'></path>
      <line x1='15' y1='45' x2='30' y2='45' />
      <line x1='15' y1='50' x2='30' y2='50' />
      <line x1='15' y1='55' x2='30' y2='55' />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const container = document.createElement('DIV');

function drawLine(){
  for(o=0;o<59;o++){
 container.innerHTML+='<span id="o'+o+'" style="position:absolute;">&bull;</span>'; 
}
  
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  for(o=0;o<59;o++){
    eval('o'+o).style.left=Math.sin(o*2/9.2)*120+120+"px";
    eval('o'+o).style.top=Math.cos(o/9.2)*120+120+"px";
  }
}drawLine();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).