# CSS/jQuery - Is it possible to create this shape (something like inverted circle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-shapes

I have no idea how would i make something like inverted circle in the corners. I have attached picture for better understanding.

[image]

Is this even possible to create using CSS3 or perhaps jQuery?

Comment: [**Round Out Corners @ CSS Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/)...but these days...SVG.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777470/wave-or-shape-with-border-on-css3/27780572#27780572) would give you options but more importantly also highlight why CSS is not recommended for this shape. It is just way too much work for something that could easily be done with SVG. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022639/how-to-draw-a-curve-by-using-div/31044421#31044421) also may be useful.

Comment: I'll vote for SVG on this one. Its possible with css, but complex shapes should really be done with **SVG**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How i would recommend create that shape **SVG**.

Css solution:
Using a before and after elements that matches the background.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 120px;
}
/*replace with "" if your going to use the code*/

.shape:before {
  content: "↙";
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-indent: 35%;
  line-height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 20px);
  left: 0;
  width: 35%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
.shape:after {
  content: "↘";
  line-height: 0%;
  text-indent: -43%;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 20px);
  right: 0;
  width: 35%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
.shape .extra {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  left: 35%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">This is not a problem any more
  <div class="extra"></div>
</div>
```

SVG:
Using the path element and then using the Bezier Curves command.
[MDN paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Curve_commands)

```html
<svg width="300px" viewbox="0 0 100 60">
  <path fill="cornflowerBlue" d="m 0,0 
                                 100,0 
                                 0,30
                                 -25,0
                                 c-5,0 -5,0 -5,5
                                 v20
                                 c0,5 0,5 -5,5
                                 h-30
                                 c-5,0 -5,0 -5,-5
                                 v-20
                                 c 0,-5 0,-5 -5,-5
                                 h-25z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The codepen link here (http://codepen.io/techsev/pen/dtAfB/) will teach you how to useadditional divs and shape them to create inverted corners.  There is no way currently to invert rounded corners without attaching additional frameworks to a style sheet.

```css
@import "compass/css3";

body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  
  
}

div.inverted-corner {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3e2a4f;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid grey 7px;
}

.top, .bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  
}

.top:before, .top:after, .bottom:before, .bottom:after{
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid grey 7px;
  border-radius: 20px; 
}

.top:before {
  top:-35px;
  left:-35px;
  
  
}

.top:after {
 top: -35px;
 right: -35px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px grey;
}

.bottom:before {
  bottom:-35px;
  left:-35px;
}

.bottom:after {
 bottom: -35px;
 right: -35px; 
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="inverted-corner">
<div class="top">&nbsp; </div>
  <h1>Hello, use mult. divs inside a div to do this</h1>
  <div class="bottom"> </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For your solution, you would increase the size of the inverted radius divs, and drop the border values so you have clean edges.  If you're looking to highlight your inverted edges, then use the correct group of top + right and top + left radii.