# Square with rounded corners and indented curved border

Tags: css, svg, border, css-shapes

I was wondering if it is possible to make a square with round corners and a indented border in pure CSS.

Currently I have this:

```
#custom-square {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     width: 75px;
     height: 75px;
     border: 2px solid #8A6EF1;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background-color: white;
}
```

[image: Squarez with rounded corners and indented border]

Comment: I do not believe it is currently possible to have curved sides with pure css.

Comment: mm oke than I make a svg of it.

Comment: There are ways of making curves with CSS, see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: @Jaketr00: It is definitely possible to do this with CSS (and with properties like border-image being available it is not as-if CSS is not the right tool for this) but SVG definitely has an edge over CSS for such curved shapes :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considering the hassle and amount of code needed to align [double curves with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986125/double-curved-shape), **SVG seems way more appropriate**. A few other reasons to go for svg here are :

- control of the path (color, width, curve...)
- control the fill with a plain color, gradient or image
- less code
- you can display it over a non plain background (gradient or image)
- maintain the boundaries of the shape for user interactions (hover, click...)

Here is a basic example using an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) with a [path element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).
The curves are drawn with [Cubic Bezier curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) :

```css
svg{width:30%;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <path d="M1.5 0.5 Q5 1 8.5 0.5 Q9.5 0.5 9.5 1.5 Q9 5 9.5 8.5 Q9.5 9.5 8.5 9.5 Q5 9 1.5 9.5 Q0.5 9.5 0.5 8.5 Q1 5 0.5 1.5 Q0.5 0.5 1.5 0.5z" 
        fill="none" stroke-width="0.2" stroke="#8A6FF2" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

Another pure CSS approach for creating this border would be to make use of `border-image` property. All that is required is create an image with the required border shape and set it to an element using the `border-image-source` property.

```css
.shape.large {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-image-source: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkh6A.png);
  border-image-width: 34px; /* the width of the border portions in the image - refer to image at the end of the answer for the exact portion details*/
  border-image-slice: 34; /* equal to border-image-width */
  border-width: 34px; /* equal to border-image-width */
}
.shape.small {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-image-source: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mra4B.png);
  border-image-width: 14px;
  border-image-slice: 14;
  border-width: 14px;
}
.shape.small.fill {
  background: aliceblue content-box;
  border-image-source: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovj03.png);
  border-width: 14px;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/abstract/2);
}
.shape.small {
  float: left;
}
.shape.large {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class='shape small'>Some content</div>
<div class='shape small fill'>Some content</div>
<div class='shape large'>Some content</div>
```

> At present this method is definitely **not much advantageous compared to SVG** but it is an option and in my opinion is better than the other CSS only approaches that are possible.

The **advantages** of this approach are:

- Very minimal and low complexity code.
- Better control over the curves and their radii (like with SVG) because the image with the required border curvature can be created separately.
- Can be placed on top of an image or a gradient background.
- Can be made to degrade gracefully (into a solid square border) in browser's that don't support it.

The **drawbacks** are:

- The container is still a square and so `hover` effects will not be restricted to the boundaries of the shape unlike with SVG.
- Adding solid color fill to the shape is possible (by using a filled version of the image) but adding a gradient or image fill is tricky because borders are still blocks (that is, there are transparent areas on either side of the curves).
- The output is responsive but as dimensions increase or decrease beyond a threshold, the shape starts to look a bit compressed or stretched. So, this is more suited for break-point based design.
- The [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) is not bad but is not great either. It works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE11+.

**Calculation of Border Image Width:**

The width or height of border area (which becomes the `border-image-width`) is nothing but the width of the portion highlighted in the below image.

[image: Highlighted portion defines border-image-width]

Answer (score 1):

This draft mock up is as close as i could get it to pure CSS, but still requires a nested div. You would need to tweak the sizing / radius for the before / after circles.

[Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLGdoq)

```
div {

  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  border: 4px solid purple;
  border-radius: 30px;
  //overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: -94px;
    content: ' ';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 4px solid purple;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 90px);
  }

  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    right: -94px;
    content: ' ';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 4px solid purple;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    clip: rect(0px, 10px, 100px, 0px);
  }
}

div > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: nice try :D but its a rough scetch of the shape.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is probably the way to go here, but here's a pretty close approximation in pure CSS. It could be made even better by increasing the size of the outer circles.

```css
#middle {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid #8A6EF1;
}
.outside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cutout {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #8A6EF1;
}
#top {
  top: -100px;
  height: 10px;
}
#right {
  top: -110px;
  left: 90px;
  width: 10px;
}
#bottom {
  top: -120px;
  height: 10px;
}
#left {
  top: -220px;
  width: 10px;
}
#top > .cutout {
  margin-top: -90px;
}
#left > .cutout {
  margin-left: -90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="middle">
  </div>
  <div id="top" class="outside">
    <div class="cutout">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="outside">
    <div class="cutout">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom" class="outside">
    <div class="cutout">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="left" class="outside">
    <div class="cutout">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```