# How to create molehill shape in CSS?

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I have a customer request to create an upside-down molehill shape underneath the header on their website.

Please see below. And I know what you're thinking, "Dang man, your paint skills are epic, please teach me". My reply to that would be "these skills can't be taught".

I have tried several things to try to get this to work, and have not been successful.

[image: Molehill shape]

Comment: Dang, check out that anti-aliasing! On another unrelated topic, could you provide us with any code you have to attempt such a feat? That would definitely help us assist you.

Comment: What have you tried so far exactly ? What didn't work ? Adding a background image ?!

Comment: First read into needed material before asking questions. Show what you have tried as @Pierre already mentioned. What you need is CSS masking. There are plenty of tutorials at the internet, eg: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/. After trying and still failing, show as your code. After that, people will help!

Comment: SVG would be the optimal method. The inner curves are quite difficult to make simply with minimal HTML / CSS.

Comment: off-topic: it looks like a... like a.. I mean :P leave it.. :p

Answer (score 3):

As [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454301/how-to-create-molehill-shape-in-css#comment60522654_36454301) mentioned, making this shape with an [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) is trivial. In the following example, I used a path element with 2 [bezier curve commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) :

```css
svg{
  display:block;
  width:30%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 5">
  <path fill="#FF7F27" d="M10 0 C7.5 0 7.5 5 5 5 S2.5 0 0 0z" />
</svg>
```

*On a side note, you can see here how aligning double curves in CSS is a hassle compared to SVG: [CSS - Double curved shape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28986125/1811992).*