# Connecting rounded squares

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

How do I create the div logo, as per the attached image below:

[image: 2 sets of connected round squares]

This is what I have created in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60jnk66d/16/)

Main issue is how do I connect the two boxes with the shape as below image, can anybody please suggest?

```css
body,html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -22.5px;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
ul li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  /*animation: dance 888ms infinite alternate;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: dance 888ms infinite alternate;
}
.block-1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #0076aa;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.block-2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #98bd81;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.block-3 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #98bd81;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.block-4 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #0076aa;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <ul class='blocks'>
    <li class='block-1'></li>
    <li class='block-2'></li>
    <li class='block-3'></li>
    <li class='block-4'></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use an SVG. It's much easier and more responsive.

Comment: Have you looked into using a `<canvas>` element?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Considering the hassle of aligning and [making double curves with *CSS*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986125/double-curved-shape), this is clearly a job for SVG. The curves are much easier to create and control. Here is an example using :

- Inline SVG
- [quadratic bezier curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves)
- [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Transformations)
- the [use element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) so there is only one occurrence of the path tag

```css
svg{ display:block; width:40%; margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 16 15">
  <defs>
    <path id="shape" d="M7 0 H10 Q11 0 11 1 V4 Q11 5 10 5 H7 Q5 5 5 7 V9 Q5 10 4 10 H1 Q0 10 0 9 V6 Q0 5 1 5 H4 Q6 5 6 3 V1 Q6 0 7 0z" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="#0076AA"/>
  <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="#98BD81" transform="translate(5,5)"/>
</svg>
```

With a loading animation :

```css
svg{ display:block; width:40%; margin:0 auto;}
.sq{ animation: opacity .6s infinite alternate; }
.gr{ animation-delay:-.6s;}
@keyframes opacity { to {opacity: 0;} }
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 16 15">
  <defs>
    <path id="shape" d="M7 0 H10 Q11 0 11 1 V4 Q11 5 10 5 H7 Q5 5 5 7 V9 Q5 10 4 10 H1 Q0 10 0 9 V6 Q0 5 1 5 H4 Q6 5 6 3 V1 Q6 0 7 0z" />
  </defs>
  <use class="sq bl" xlink:href="#shape" fill="#0076AA"/>
  <use class="sq gr" xlink:href="#shape" fill="#98BD81" transform="translate(5,5)"/>
</svg>
```

*Note that you will need to add vendor prefixes in the animation and that animations on svg elements aren't supported by IE/Edge.*

Answer (score 8):

I managed to create the design you were looking for by adding a few pseudo-elements to your CSS. I was a bit pressed for time so it's a little rough around the edges, but hopefully it will be of some help:

```css
body,html{
    background-color:#fff;
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper{
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-22.5px;
    margin-left:-22.5px;
}
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:82px;
    height:82px;
    position:relative;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
ul li{
    width:2em;
    height:2em;
    position:absolute;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
.block-1{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#0076aa;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.block-2{
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:#98bd81;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.block-3{
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background:#98bd81;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.block-4{
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#0076aa;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.block-1::before,.block-2::before{
    background:inherit;
    content:"";
    top:calc(100% - 5px);
    left:-50%;
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    width:100%;
}
.block-3::before,.block-4::before{
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    content:"";
    height:calc(50% + 3px);
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(-50% - 3px);
    width:calc(50% + 3px);
}
.block-3::after,.block-4::after{
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    content:"";
    height:calc(50% + 3px);
    position:absolute;
    right:calc(-50% - 3px);
    top:-3px;
    width:calc(50% + 3px);
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <ul class='blocks'>
        <li class='block-1'></li>
        <li class='block-2'></li>
        <li class='block-3'></li>
        <li class='block-4'></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your best option is to use an SVG.

You can either run it through an image to SVG converter which gives you a fully finished SVG, create the SVG code by hand or use a program like Illustrator to achieve your desired effect.

---

## Image to SVG Convert

This is using an SVG converter tool online to create the code. As you can see its quite full

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 900 904" version="1.1">
<path fill="#0176aa" d=" M 350.14 0.00 L 546.51 0.00 C 557.90 0.78 568.99 5.90 576.59 14.48 C 583.89 22.42 588.07 33.18 587.88 43.98 C 587.88 107.98 587.88 171.99 587.88 235.99 C 588.17 249.96 580.94 263.65 569.60 271.71 C 561.12 277.92 550.43 280.52 540.01 279.83 C 487.44 278.44 434.85 271.78 382.24 276.12 C 362.32 277.82 342.25 280.95 323.63 288.51 C 310.06 294.06 297.18 302.66 289.17 315.19 C 282.70 325.19 279.87 337.18 279.77 349.00 C 279.78 413.00 279.76 477.00 279.78 541.00 C 279.91 547.26 278.86 553.57 276.37 559.33 C 269.95 574.91 253.92 585.94 237.04 586.14 C 176.69 586.22 116.34 586.15 56.00 586.17 C 47.31 586.07 38.35 586.89 30.00 583.93 C 13.22 578.53 0.73 562.25 0.00 544.61 L 0.00 346.86 C 1.21 331.57 10.80 317.30 24.66 310.68 C 30.65 307.78 37.31 306.21 43.97 306.34 C 78.64 306.38 113.32 306.11 147.98 305.13 C 176.85 303.95 205.87 302.67 234.30 297.14 C 250.18 293.88 266.27 289.25 279.60 279.68 C 289.65 272.50 297.23 262.16 301.52 250.61 C 308.30 232.56 309.35 213.05 310.12 193.97 C 310.41 178.31 310.35 162.64 309.88 146.99 C 309.15 112.31 308.05 77.64 308.19 42.95 C 308.23 32.02 312.83 21.27 320.42 13.44 C 328.11 5.34 339.00 0.56 350.14 0.00 Z"/>
<path fill="#98bd82" d=" M 631.90 331.91 C 640.05 323.06 651.95 317.87 663.99 317.91 C 728.00 317.88 792.02 317.89 856.04 317.91 C 873.26 317.68 889.87 328.70 896.45 344.60 C 898.66 349.76 899.86 355.36 899.85 360.98 C 899.86 422.00 899.86 483.02 899.86 544.03 C 899.84 552.43 900.48 561.14 897.25 569.10 C 891.45 585.30 875.35 597.26 858.09 597.69 C 841.41 597.85 824.75 596.63 808.11 595.64 C 766.00 593.26 723.59 590.29 681.55 595.31 C 662.45 597.77 643.15 601.81 626.03 610.97 C 614.00 617.36 603.35 627.05 597.60 639.56 C 593.43 648.42 591.80 658.29 591.75 668.03 C 591.77 731.04 591.73 794.04 591.76 857.05 C 591.92 862.96 591.45 868.98 589.40 874.58 C 583.95 890.84 568.25 902.80 551.17 904.00 L 351.77 904.00 C 336.62 902.43 322.55 892.77 316.15 878.88 C 312.84 872.11 311.79 864.49 311.89 857.02 C 311.92 797.01 311.90 737.00 311.90 676.99 C 311.82 668.81 311.68 660.36 314.76 652.63 C 320.59 636.73 336.31 624.97 353.29 624.28 C 404.78 623.97 456.37 624.47 507.73 620.29 C 528.90 618.29 550.27 615.67 570.40 608.50 C 584.50 603.46 597.97 595.10 606.37 582.42 C 616.43 567.35 619.46 548.95 621.06 531.25 C 623.56 498.87 621.71 466.38 621.22 433.96 C 620.48 409.99 620.21 386.00 620.20 362.01 C 619.94 350.95 624.36 339.95 631.90 331.91 Z"/>
</svg>
```

---

## Hand coded SVG

Ive only half done this and its not perfect but you can see what I'm getting at. It is also much easier to read and understand than the output of the converter.

```html
<svg height="400" viewbox="0 0 400 400">
    <path fill="blue"
          d="M145,0
             L200,0
             Q220,0 220,20
             L220,75
             Q220,95 200,95
             L185,95
             Q145,90 135,110
             L135,165
             Q135,185 115,185
             L60,185
             Q40,185 40,165
             L40,110
             Q40,90 60,90
             L75,90
             Q115,95 120,70
             L120,20
             Q120,0 140,0z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a half-formulated answer. Not sure if you can make the blur less translucent but here's as far as I got.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
.filter {
  -webkit-filter: url("#goo");
  filter: url("#goo");
}
.block {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}
.filter {
  height: 4em;
}
.block1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 2em, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 2em, 0);
  background: #0076aa;
}
.block2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(2em, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(2em, 0, 0);
  background: #0076aa;
}
.block3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(2em, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(2em, 0, 0);
  background: #98bd81;
}
.block4 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(4em, -2em, 0);
  transform: translate3d(4em, -2em, 0);
  background: #98bd81;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <div class="block block1"></div>
  <div class="block block2"></div>
</div>
<div class="filter">
  <div class="block block3"></div>
  <div class="block block4"></div>
</div>

<!-- filters -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 16 -7" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

I know you have an answer now, but here's another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Logo** is already develop by **great developer** but i have done small changes in css to reduce the code and apply `transform : skew` :

[image: LOGO]

```css
body{
  background-color: #efefef;
}
ul{
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
.square{
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.bg-odd{
  background: #0076aa;
}
.bg-even{
  background: #98bd81;
  margin-left: 15px;
  right: -75px;
  top: 75px;
}
li:nth-child(1):before, 
li:nth-child(2):before{
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  left: -60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 0px);
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
  width: 100%;
}
li:nth-child(1):before{
  background: #0076aa;
}
li:nth-child(2):before{
  background: #98bd81;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <ul class='blocks'>
    <li class='square bg-odd'></li>
    <li class='square bg-even'></li>
    <li class='square bg-odd'></li>
    <li class='square bg-even'></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```