# Draw double curved item with beveled edges

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm creating a website, with a header / menu on top. 
In the middle, there is a logo. To accentuate this, I've absolute positioned an ellips below the logo: So underneath, you see the ellips, which blends in perfectly with the rest of the menu.

```
.ellips {
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 130%;
        background: white;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 6%;
        border: 2px solid #dfe0e4;
    }
```

[image: Absolutely positioned ellips]

Now the client wants to see the left and right 'corner' also curved:

[image]

I know that the 'shove an ellips beneath the menu' approach won't suffice.
I was thinking about 2 possible solutions:

1. Create an SVG with the curve, and place it beneath the menu. I've tried that solution, but I'm no SVG expert, so I went to try a CSS approach:
2. Try to create CSS item (div) with such curve: above it's white, below it's transparent. Put dat item below the menu.

I prefer a css solution, as I'm no big hero in SVG. But if it can be achieved much easier with SVG. Then I'd take that solution off course.

Edit: The blue-ish background you see, is an underlaying image. So this needs to be transparant.

The ellips needs to be colored white.

[image]

Comment: You can use a SVG to directly shape your HTML elements: https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/
Could it help?

Comment: It could help. But I'm not capable of creating an SVG with that shape..

Comment: @sjahan mind, that the CSS `clip-path` property is currently still an experimental feature and not supported by all common browsers. [Here's the support overview](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

Comment: @NamelessLambda true, I've already used it but it only works on webkit browser on complex shapes I think... :/

Comment: Install an SVG editor such as Inkscape and draw whatever SVG shape you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created 2 `SVG` examples so you can choose where to apply the background

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/PQZqgY?editors=1100)

---

The outer container of each `SVG` element keeps a specific aspect ratio so the whole element can be responsive (but, of course, you can also specify a fixed width or height).

The basic idea is to create a `path` that *overflows* the size of the `SVG` element, so you can define a closed shape on the top area or on the bottom area, in order to fill it with a colour (if you enlarged the `viewbox` e.g. to `-10 -10 610 130` you could see how the path is actually defined).

The applied background is a gradient but you can also specify a single color-stop (white, in your specific scenario). The background on the body element shows the transparent parts of the `SVG`.

*Fine tuning and adjustment of curves, viewbox, colours is left to the reader.*

For any change to the shape you can read the [path documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

**Markup**

```
<div class="doublecurve">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 600 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#d8e5f1" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#91b4d3" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <path class="concave" fill="url(#gradient)" d="M-2 2 
            L75 2 A75 75 0 0 1 110 20 C200 100 400 100 480 20
            A75 75 0 0 1 525 2 L602 2 L602 122 L-2 122 z"/>
  </svg>
</div>



<div class="doublecurve">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 600 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#d8e5f1"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#91b4d3"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <path class="concave" fill="url(#gradient)" d="M-2 2 
            L75 2 A75 75 0 0 1 110 20 C200 100 400 100 480 20
            A75 75 0 0 1 525 2 L602 2 L602 -2 L-2-2"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.doublecurve {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px dashed #bc9;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  position: relative; }

.doublecurve svg { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;}

.doublecurve path.concave { 
  stroke: #d0d0d0; 
  stroke-width: 4px;}
```

---

**Final Result**

[image]

Comment: Yeah an svg guy ! Better than our css solutions. I need to learn it.

Comment: @AlexVand Actually I had no idea how to do it since 1 hour ago. :)

Comment: Are you Kyle XY ?

Comment: Is this somewhat easily scaleable?

Comment: it is responsive as I explained. Try to resize the output window

Comment: The upper lines are not straight. Is there a tool where I can edit the path easily? (You can see when you try to narrow down the viewport). Specially the upperright line is a bet skew

Comment: Now I'm capable of better understanding SVG. Just 1 small question: Did you use a tool to draw the SVG's, or are you just very good with Maths? ;)

Comment: None of the above. I've just imagined the coordinates of each line and curve. It's not really difficult, it's really just a bit of practice.

Answer (score 1):

SVG would be the way to go for such things but for a CSS solution I would probably use multiple background with linear/radial-gradient **BUT** the drawback is that it can be difficult to calculate the different values and make the whole shape responsive.

Here is an example that can help you get some idea:

```css
body {
  background:grey;
}

.header {
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  background: 
  radial-gradient(ellipse at -7px 26px, transparent 50%, red 50%, red calc(50% + 11px), white 0%) 101px -3px/7% 19% no-repeat, 
  radial-gradient(ellipse at 60px 26px, transparent 50%, red 50%, red calc(50% + 11px), white 0%) 454px -4px/7% 19% no-repeat, 
  radial-gradient(ellipse at top, white 20%, red 20%, red calc(21% + 2px), transparent 0%) 50% 0/200% 200% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(red 50%,transparent 0%) 0 0/100% 10px no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to right, gray, blue);
}
.header-tr {
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin-top:20px;
  border-top: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  background: 
  radial-gradient(ellipse at -7px 26px, transparent 50%, red 50%, red calc(50% + 11px), white 0%) 101px -3px/7% 19% no-repeat, 
  radial-gradient(ellipse at 60px 26px, transparent 50%, red 50%, red calc(50% + 11px), white 0%) 454px -4px/7% 19% no-repeat, 
  radial-gradient(ellipse at top, white 20%, red 20%, red calc(21% + 2px), transparent 0%) 50% 0/200% 200% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(red 50%,transparent 0%) 0 0/110px 10px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(red 50%,transparent 0%) 100% 0/110px 10px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>

<div class="header-tr">

</div>
```

And if you are open to use multiple element you can rely on pseudo element and some border-radius but you have also to manage a lot of element:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  right: 80px;
  left: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: calc(100% - 11px);
  left: -80px;
  border-top: 18px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0 50% 0 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  height: 52px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.top:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: calc(100% - 11px);
  right: -80px;
  border-top: 18px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  height: 52px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.header:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(100% - 88px);
  left: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 0 50% 0 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.header:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 88px);
  right: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="top"></div>
</div>
```

And here is an SVG solution:

```html
<svg
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  viewBox='0 0 75 50'
  width='600' height='300'
  fill='transparent'>
  <path d='M0 24 L64 24 L64 2 L58 2 C36 2 46 10 32 10 C18 10 26 2 4 2 L0 2 Z' stroke="red" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: The problem is: The gradient you've drawn, is an image. So that part should be transparent. And the Ellips must be white.

Comment: @KornelitoBenito yes we can relplace everything with transparent ;) i will update

Comment: Is the upperside then also white? And not 'transparant'? Also, I asume that the border width can be thinner?

Comment: @KornelitoBenito yes white, but i can manage to make it transaprent if you want :) .. i updated my answer to make the inside tranparent.

Comment: @KornelitoBenito and yes the border can be thiner but as i said it's a bit difficult to manage all the different values as you have to change many values at the same time

Comment: I need to get the border @ 2px solid #dfe0e4. But that is something I can try to achieve. I'm no hero in background. This seems pretty advanced stuff ;). Thanks!

Comment: @KornelitoBenito i added another solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Almost there ... it could get you in the way.

I used `::before` and `::after` on the header to add two curve.

Play a little with the values of the radius to get what you want.

The ellips has a fixed width, so this is as responsive as possible. When resizing the screen, the corners won't break but the ellip's size won't change.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #d2e1f1, #86acd0);
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}
header::before, header::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: calc(50% - 80px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 6px solid #dadbe0;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
header::before {
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 140px 0px 0px/0px 60px 0px 0px;
}
header::after {
  right: 0px;
  border-radius: 140px 0px 0px 0px/60px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.ellips {
  background: white;
  height: 120px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 90% 90%/0px 0px 90px 90px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  border: 6px solid #dadbe0;
}

.masks {
  background: white;
  height: 9px;
  width: 330px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 90% 90%/0px 0px 90px 90px;
  bottom: -8px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="ellips">
  </div>
  <div class="masks"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: is there a easy way to control the curve with this solution ... as i also tried to code something like this but couldn't get a big curve

Comment: I'm trying right now ^^. don't want to leave it like this

Comment: am trying too :)

Comment: In this way, I can control the border even more! trying this right now!

Comment: oh ... two px ... ^^ okay, lets try.

Comment: I think you should try SVG ... look at this stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548827/how-to-make-a-curved-header-with-svg-or-with-another-responsive-solution, in the answer he makes a beautiful curve

Answer (score 1):

Here is an inline-SVG solution with a quadratic bezier curve.
The svg image has 500x50 pixels dimensions and is absolute positioned into the header.

```css
.your-header {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfe0e4;
  position: relative;

  /* These two are just for demo */
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 75px;
}

svg.ellipse {
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  /* Centers the svg horizontal */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  position: absolute;
  /* 2px up due to the parents border */
  top: -2px;
}

svg.ellipse > .border-clear{
  /* A white line to cover up the parents border */
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

svg.ellipse>.wave {
  stroke: #dfe0e4;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-header">
  <svg class="ellipse">
    <path d="M0 0 H499" class="border-clear" />
    <path d="M0 1 Q 62.5 1, 125 26 T 250 49 T 375 26 T 500 1" class="wave"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```