# How to create a curve between two gradient using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I have two divs with distinct gradient background and I need to create a S-Shape curve between them.

[image]

Here's the example fiddle for gradient divs: https://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/rjyfc46c/2/

```css
#section1{
    height:200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ad3, #add);
}
#section2{
    height:200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #de350b, #0065ff);
}
```

```html
<div id="section1"></div>
<div id="section2"></div>
```

There are couple of things which crossed my mind but:

**- svg:** don't know how to handle other gradient div.
**- border-radius:** failed to get truly S-like curve plus it gets ugly when I resize the screen.
**- clip-path:** not supported by some browsers https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path
**- png image:** nope! needs to be dynamic content.

any help would be appreciated!

---

P.S: a must read for future readers: https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/

Comment: I'm trying to think of a way but thusfar cant. You only need one of them to curve and position it slighly over the other

Comment: Cant you use the SVG for one half?

Comment: Sorry martin I'm not good in creating svg's.. is it possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a solution using [linearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients) with SVG.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #de350b, #0065ff);
}
svg {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg mlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox="0 0 64 64">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ad3" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#add" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <path d='M0 10 C30 28 38 0 64 10 L64 0 L0 0 Z'  fill="url(#grad)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[image: SVG curve gradients]

Here is also a useful [online tool](http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0%2010%20C30%2028%2038%200%2064%2010%20L64%200%20L0%200%20Z) to easily edit the shape (simply append the path to the URL to edit it`http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0 10 C30 28 38 0 64 10 L64 0 L0 0 Z` )

---

Another idea with the same SVG used as a background so you can easily handle content above it:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="500" ><defs><linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="%23ad3" /><stop offset="100%" stop-color="%23add" /></linearGradient></defs><path d="M0 10 C30 28 38 0 64 10 L64 0 L0 0 Z"  fill="url(%23grad)"/></svg>'), 
  linear-gradient(to bottom right, #de350b, #0065ff);
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p>TOP</p>
<p>BOTTOM</p>
</div>
```

---

In case you want a pure CSS solution with no SVG involved here is one using `mask` and radial-gradient:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ad3, #add);
}
.box:after {
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(100% 80% at top   ,white 79.5%,transparent 80%) left,
    radial-gradient(100% 80% at bottom,transparent 79.5%,white 80%) right;
  mask:
    radial-gradient(100% 80% at top   ,white 79.5%,transparent 80%) left,
    radial-gradient(100% 80% at bottom,transparent 79.5%,white 80%) right;
  -webkit-mask-size:50.1% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask-size:50.1% 100%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #de350b, #0065ff);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

[image: CSS curve linear gradient mask]

Adjust the different values to control the curve. The trick is to make sure both are the same and start at the same point to create a contiguous shape. You can introduce CSS variables to easily control this:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  margin:10px;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ad3, #add);
}
.box:after {
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(var(--r1,100%) var(--r2,80%) at top   ,white 79.5%,transparent 80%) left,
    radial-gradient(var(--r1,100%) var(--r2,80%) at bottom,transparent 79.5%,white 80%) right;
  mask:
    radial-gradient(var(--r1,100%) var(--r2,80%) at top   ,white 79.5%,transparent 80%) left,
    radial-gradient(var(--r1,100%) var(--r2,80%) at bottom,transparent 79.5%,white 80%) right;
  -webkit-mask-size:50.1% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask-size:50.1% 100%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #de350b, #0065ff);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--r1:82%;--r2:97%">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--r1:126%;--r2:72%">

</div>
```

[image: CSS mask gradient curve]

To make things funnier we can add a border between both gradient following the curve where we can place another gradient!

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  margin:10px;
  position:relative;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,blue,black);
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:calc(100% - var(--b,10px)); /*control the gap here*/
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(var(--r1,100%) var(--r2,80%) at var(--p1,top)   ,white 79.5%,transparent 80%) var(--d1,right),
    radial-gradient(var(--r1,100%) var(--r2,80%) at var(--p2,bottom),transparent 79.5%,white 80%) var(--d2,left);
  mask:
    radial-gradient(var(--r1,100%) var(--r2,80%) at var(--p1,top)   ,white 79.5%,transparent 80%) var(--d1,right),
    radial-gradient(var(--r1,100%) var(--r2,80%) at var(--p2,bottom),transparent 79.5%,white 80%) var(--d2,left);
  -webkit-mask-size:50.1% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask-size:50.1% 100%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.box:before {
  top:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #de350b, #0065ff);
}
.box:after {
  bottom:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ad3, #add);
  --p1:bottom;
  --p2:top;
  --d1:left;
  --d2:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--r1:82%;--r2:97%;--b:20px">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--r1:126%;--r2:72%;--b:5px">

</div>
```

[image: CSS curve shape multiple gradients]

Comment: thanks this seems to work. How can I gracefully modify the curve.. that path element is having many values. Also how did you convert it to background-image in second snippet?

Comment: @JerryGoyal well, to modify the curve it's not easy unless you understand how all the value work with path ... i generaly use tool to generate them, so i advise you to do the same, you can find a lot of them online, here is one i use http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0%20100%20C150%20200%20350%200%20500%20100%20L500%200%20L0%200%20Z [zoom - to see the shape] ... for the background as you can see i simply copied the svg, that's all

Comment: @JerryGoyal i added more detail and i used a more easy curve to edit ;)

Comment: @JerryGoyal in case you are still intrested, I added another solution