# create curved div without image

Tags: html, css

I want to replicate an image effect. On this page https://inventi.studio/en you can see some div containers with "waves". The curved effect is achieved by uploading an image as a background.

So this is what I currently have

```css
#box {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #47b784, #009d90 26%, #00818e 50%, #25647b 74%, #36495d);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>

<div id="page">
  Content starts here
</div>
```

and this is what I tried to achieve

```css
#wave {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #47b784;
}

#wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 340px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  right: -5px;
  top: 40px;
}

#wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #47b784;
  left: 0;
  top: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wave">
</div>

<div id="page">
  content starts here
</div>
```

but as you can see the div below the curved div gets covered. I am trying to achieve this effect with one single div container that is not overlapping other ones.

[image: example]

How can I achieve this with one div container and no image as a background?

Comment: just add margin-bottom to the #wave ?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669689/good-way-to-create-a-curve-between-two-gradient-divs-in-css/49670229#49670229

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just add padding top to page equal to the top of the wave `before`?

```css
#wave {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #47b784;
}

#wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 340px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  right: 0;
  top: 39px;
}

#wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #47b784;
  left: 0;
  top: 27px;
}

#page {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wave">
</div>

<div id="page">
  content starts here
</div>
```