# Creating CSS wave shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuF8T.png)

I would like to archive this kind of shape using CSS.

```
#wave {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: inherit;
  background: #e0efe3;
}

<div id="wave"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide some more representative html and css. Make it as easy a possible for us to help you by proving a reasonable attempt

Comment: I added an image @JonP please

Comment: What i wanted is my page to have two waves like those in the picture filled the whole page, I can do the fill but the shape is my problem

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Whats on the code @AHaworth

Comment: Have you looked at all at anything? Like SVGs or gradients or border radius or...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49669689/8620333

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wavy shape with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css)

Comment: @AHaworth not that good in SVG's that's why i opt for css... the goodness with Mohd Abdul Mujib answer it worked.. thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using `border-radius`, `relative positioning` a little `CSS gradient` and some `z-index`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="topdiv">Top Content</div>
<div class="overlapdiv"></div>
<div class="bottomdiv">Bottom Content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.topdiv {
  background-color: #911bc9;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.overlapdiv {
  top: -100px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(168, 57, 224, 1) 0%,rgba(168, 57, 224, 1) 50%,rgba(145, 27, 201, 1) 50%,rgba(145, 27, 201, 1) 100%);
}
.bottomdiv {
  background-color: #a839e0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0 100px 0 0;
  top: -200px;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/abBJoaQ)**

Comment: I wanted it to fit screen, so i added some java-script to control responsiveness, it worked. thanks.

Comment: Awesome!, you could make it fit using just `width:100%;` for all the divs.