# Wavy top div css

Tags: html, css

I have looked around on the web and found a few good solutions on how to make a wavy div on the bottom but I could not find anything on how to make the top wavy. This is what I was attempting to reverse to make it on top: https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/

Here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish (The wavy top with css, bottom is straight). Any help would be great

[image]

Comment: found this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css

Comment: I think your best bet is to follow the example of the article you included and create an SVG that lives in your footer.

Comment: It is possible by using `clip-path`. In your case it should be tricky to generate wavy form, but check this: http://blog.2wav.com/how-we-did-it-clip-path/ - seems to be a good example how to create a similar shape using svg

Comment: @flbas1 this one is for a wavy bottom, but how do I invert that?