# How to achieve a curved ramp effect in css

Tags: html, css

[image]

In the image above you can see how it has a very nice curved effect end to end.

[image]

But the image above this text is all I can achieve. This is by using `border-radius: 50%;` but this just does not give it the same affect.

Not sure if anyone knows if this is possible to do or not?

I was thinking of creating it as an image as that might be easier.

Comment: this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css

Comment: @RV Thanks for this, this does look promising and I will look into that.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.withimg{
 background-color: #000;
 text-align: center;
}

.withimg img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 50px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}
.belowbox{
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #10141d;
}
```

```html
<div class="withimg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200" alt="">            
</div>
<div class="belowbox"></div>
```

Comment: This looks nice, but hasn't got the curved affect where the 2 ends connect.