# How to create a text fill wave effect?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to use **pure css** to realize the wave **animation** effect in the **text**, the **height** of the wave can be **controlled**, and the wave **image is not used**.

[image: CSS fill wave text effect]

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
span {
    font-size: 10em;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    position: relative;
}
span::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    z-index: -1
}
span::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: lightpink;
    z-index: -2;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span>FILL</span>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to answer the question here, I'm hoping someone with better knowledge would. but till then may I suggest you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css and try animating it and masking it.

Comment: Look at bakground-clip and animated background gradients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will first start by building the wave animation using background like below:

```css
.box {
  background:
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at top   ,red   99%,green) calc(0*100%/3) 0,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at bottom,green 99%,red  ) calc(3*100%/3) 0,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at top   ,red   99%,green) calc(6*100%/3) 0,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at bottom,green 99%,red  ) calc(9*100%/3) 0;
  background-size:50% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  animation: move 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    background-position:
       calc(-6*100%/3) 0,
       calc(-3*100%/3) 0,
       calc(0*100%/3) 0,
       calc(3*100%/3) 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Then I will add text and color it with that background:

```css
.box {
  background:
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at top   ,red   99%,green) calc(0*100%/3) 0,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at bottom,green 99%,red  ) calc(3*100%/3) 0,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at top   ,red   99%,green) calc(6*100%/3) 0,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at bottom,green 99%,red  ) calc(9*100%/3) 0;
  background-size:50% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
  background-clip:text;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:100px;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  animation: move 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    background-position:
       calc(-6*100%/3) 0,
       calc(-3*100%/3) 0,
       calc(0*100%/3) 0,
       calc(3*100%/3) 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> FILL</div>
```

Related question to understand the logic behind the background values: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333)

---

To control the height of the wave we adjust the `background-size`:

```css
.box {
  background:
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at top   ,red   99%,green) calc(0*100%/3) 0,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at bottom,green 99%,red  ) calc(3*100%/3) 0,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at top   ,red   99%,green) calc(6*100%/3) 0,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at bottom,green 99%,red  ) calc(9*100%/3) 0
    green;
  background-size:50% 200%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
  background-clip:text;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:100px;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  animation:
    move 1s infinite linear,
    up   5s infinite linear alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    background-position:
       calc(-6*100%/3) 0,
       calc(-3*100%/3) 0,
       calc(0*100%/3) 0,
       calc(3*100%/3) 0;
  }
}

@keyframes up {
  to {
    background-size:50% 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> FILL</div>
```

Also like below:

```css
.box {
  background:
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at top   ,transparent   99%,green) calc(0*100%/3) 0/50.1% 180%,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at bottom,green 99%,transparent  ) calc(3*100%/3) 0/50.1% 180%,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at top   ,transparent   99%,green) calc(6*100%/3) 0/50.1% 180%,
    radial-gradient(100% 58% at bottom,green 99%,transparent  ) calc(9*100%/3) 0/50.1% 180%,
    linear-gradient(green,green) bottom/100% 0%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:100px;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  animation:
    move 1s infinite linear,
    up   5s infinite linear alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    background-position:
       calc(-6*100%/3) 0,
       calc(-3*100%/3) 0,
       calc(0*100%/3)  0,
       calc(3*100%/3)  0,
       bottom;
  }
}

@keyframes up {
  to {
    background-size: 
      50.1% 20%,
      50.1% 20%,
      50.1% 20%,
      50.1% 20%,
      100%  80%;
  }
}

body {
 background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> FILL</div>
```

Comment: If the final `radial-gradient` adds **color**, the text will have a shadow. No color, the text will be hidden

this is [test](https://codepen.io/abawn/pen/KKgqBqK)

Comment: @Purpleawn I don't understand your comment

Comment: This method will make the font have a green border. Can you remove this border?

Comment: @Purpleawn remove the last color and change the 50% to 50.1% in the background-size

Comment: after deleting the last color, the border disappeared. But changing the `background-size-y` value will make the text cropped

Comment: @Purpleawn `background-size:50.1% Y` you change the first value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226167/discussion-between-purple-awn-and-temani-afif).

Comment: @Purpleawn check the update, added another snippet