# How do we make a wave shape out of a div in css?

Tags: html, css, frontend, styling

In CSS, what property can we use to make a wave-like shape out of a div? I tried using the border tag but it doesn't work.
This is the shape I want to make:

[how I want the div shaped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9c9N.png)

And here is the main code and container:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.wave{
background-color:#0a95ff;

width:100%;
height:300px;


}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wave"> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hope this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css

Answer (score -1):

Maybe make a half circle and put them side-by-side.