# CSS Wave Background using Before and After pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Clarification:
This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css) is using svg and I wanted to use plain css for my problem. Also, my `output 2` is no where near the solution given found in the link.

I am practicing css by following a background design in html. These are the outputs that I want to follow.

`output 1`

[image: image_1]

`output 2`

[image: image_2]

My problem is that I do not know how to use `before` and `after` pseudo elements in css so I do not know how to create these two wave thingy. Can someone with beast css knowledge help me get through this?

Currently, I have this setup:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    :root {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #A895E0 0%, #6D4CD8 35.86%, #6D4CD8 100%);
}

.pinkish {
    height: 768px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(104.42deg, #F7F6FD 0.08%, #FA7086 89.17%);
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
    filter: blur(75px);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="wrapper">
        <div class="pinkish">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="curve"></div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wavy shape with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css)

Comment: @Sfili_81 not really, as much as possible, I want to use css and not svg.

Comment: hum think about clip-path? Tip if you search on google you can find a lot of material about wavy css