# What should be done to add the blue part in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web, deployment

I am new to HTML and CSS, and was trying to create the following pic:
[image]

I have done every part of the picture but just can't understand how to add the light blue part at the bottom, or what it is called. I have tried shaping different divs but nothing seems to work It would be really helpful if somebody could explain to me how to add such designs without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css). The suggested solution would be to use the SVG element. If you are trying to learn HTML and CSS, I think this would be a great path forward.

Alternatively, if you just need it to look like the picture, you can recreate the background in a photo editor (e.g. Photoshop or Paint.NET), and then use the **background-image** property:

```
background-image: url("my-background.png");
```